# Deleted GarageBand but taking up space

Tags: storage

I deleted GarageBand by dragging the app to the trash, but in the system information it says it is still taking up over 20gb, where are these files located?
[image]

Comment: Just had a look, the `/Library/Audio` folder is only 800mb

Comment: AH but running `mdfind -name Garageband` led me to find `/Library/Application Support/GarageBand` which is 11gb

Comment: Grand Perspective at http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/ is great for finding what folders and/or files are taking up lots of room.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed loops - you'll have to clean them out: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201503

If you made projects, they could be stored anywhere on the disk - probably in a /Users folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem if the people above did not help, take these steps:

1. Download OmniDiskSweeper (a comprehensive file removal app) from the App Store.
2. Open the app and click your main drive.
3. Give the application about 5 minutes to size your driver
4. GarageBand and the loops should be under the same folder I'm pretty sure its either "Users" or "Applications", click the item you would like to delete and press the "delete" button on the bottom right of the application.

You can also use this app to delete unnecessary files or garbage files. Please try not to delete any files that seem unfamiliar to you because you could harm your computer integrity! I do not claim any liability or responsibility for any mistakes or files you may accidentally delete!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing (or moving) files from the following locations:

- `/Library/Audio/Apple Loops` (system-wide)
- `/Library/Application Support/GarageBand`  (system-wide)
- `~/Library/Application Support/GarageBand` (user's files)
- `~/Library/Audio/Apple Loops`  (user's  files)

You can also try locating the files by `locate` command, e.g.:

```
locate GarageBand
```

<sup>Note: To rebuild db for the first time, run: `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`.</sup>